# Electromagnetism - role of the phase between fundamental invariants?

Tags: electromagnetism

The two Lorentz invariants are $\mathbf{E}^2-\mathbf{B}^2$ and $2\mathbf{E}\cdot \mathbf{B}$.

It is common in the literature to construct a complex vector:

$$
\mathbf{F}=\mathbf{E}+i\mathbf{B}
$$

whose square produces the Lorentz invariants:

$$
\mathbf{F}^2=\mathbf{E}^2-\mathbf{B}^2+2i\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{B}
$$

Since this is a complex number, one can certainly understand it using the usual Euler equation:

$$
\mathbf{F}=R \exp (i \theta)
$$

where

$$
R=\sqrt{(\mathbf{E}^2-\mathbf{B}^2)^2+4(\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{B})^2}\\
\theta=\arctan(2\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{B}/ (\mathbf{E}^2-\mathbf{B}^2))
$$

Is there a place for $\mathbf{F}$, expressed using a phase $\theta$ and a length $R$ in the formulation of electromagnetism? Can one formulate electromagnetism using a phase/magnitude combo?

Answer (score 1):

The norm squared of $\textbf{F}$ is the energy density of the electromagnetic field, meaning that the hamiltonian formulation would use it instead of $\text{Re}(\textbf{F}^2)$. I suspect that the phase is not useful because the $E. B$ invariant is a total derivative.